# How to get Days since last session in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get Days since last session out of my raw GA data in BigQuery. I see visitStartTime for the current session, but how can I get the previous session time?

Comment: You want days going back from today's date or from the last session the user had? In other words, if the customer had just 1 session 3 days ago, would the result be `null` or 3?

Comment: If the same customer is visiting the site again today, it will be 3, corresponding to the Days since last session dimension available in the GA Audience - Behavior - Frequency & Recency report. I want to run a daily report, so if the visit is just one and happened 3 days ago, the dimension will be 0 for this day, and this visitor won't appear in today's report at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need but hopefully this gives you some insights on getting previous days:

```
SELECT
  fv,
  IF(dts IS NULL, NULL, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", dts), DAY) ) count_days
FROM(
  SELECT 
    fullvisitorid fv,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT date ORDER BY date DESC)[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] dts
  FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
  GROUP BY 1
)
```

As you said in your comment, you'll be running this analyzes daily so I used the `CURRENT_DATE()` variable as reference.

It gives for each customer how many days passed since last session. If there's no session before, then it returns `NULL` (so you can keep absolute values for reference in your analyzes).

You can play around with this query and adapt as you see fit, such as taking averages of past days since last session and so on.

Comment: Thanks Willian, I tried the above but got null for all visitors. Should I change the current date to yesterday as the current day table is not available yet?

Comment: Please try again the query I've edited. I made a mistake when writing it down and ended up selecting 0 days.