# Days since last session by Google Analytics userID in BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I need to get get the **days since last session** of our users, that are identified by userid.

Note: there are similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788338/days-since-last-session-for-users-with-session-level-custom-dimension-bigque) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431418/how-to-get-days-since-last-session-in-bigquery)) but without a defenitive answer.

> We are sending the `userid` as a custom dimension with index 2.

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>> at [2:22]
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    customDimensions.value,
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(MAX(visitStartTime)) AS LastSesion,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS toDay,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(MAX(visitStartTime)), DAY) AS daysSinceLastSession
FROM
  `ga-360-tvgo.76246634.ga_sessions_*`
GROUP BY
  1
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by an array. You need to choose a value from the array or aggregate it somehow - you can use `unnest()` to run SQL on arrays, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=2) AS userId,
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(MAX(visitStartTime)) AS LastSesion,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS toDay,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(MAX(visitStartTime)), DAY) AS daysSinceLastSession
FROM
  `ga-360-tvgo.76246634.ga_sessions_*`
GROUP BY
  1
```

Comment: So you access the parent object (customDimensions), unnest it, filter by index == 2, and get the value. I was trying to access directly the property value with `customDimensions.value`. I didn't know you shouldn't do that. Ty.

Comment: `unnest()` turns an array into table format. Within the array are structs that `unnest()` turns into columns. Everything happens lateral, i.e. per row.